# Remove low quality answers from the review queue if question is closed

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, low-quality-posts

It seems to me a waste of reviewers' time to review answers to questions that are already closed. And there is a high correlation of poor answers to poor questions, because experienced users of this site generally do not attempt to answer poor questions.

Along the same lines, perhaps answers to questions that have close votes should be moved to the end of the queue to de-prioritize them.

Comment: So the same type of lousy answers that get those questions closed in the first place are then given lower priority just because they can't multiply on that question? How does that help anything?

Comment: What do you mean with "review and close answers"?

Comment: @NathanTuggy If the question is closed, there won't be many people looking at its answers anyway. Why take time to review something no one will see?

Comment: The assertion that no one looks at closed questions seems contrary to a great deal of experience. People *do*, and, not infrequently, use them as examples of what to ask, or references for their own problems. Voting is not disabled on closed questions, and SEO is the same.

Comment: @NathanTuggy That sounds like another problem that should also be solved. By the way, I think I misunderstood one of your initial points. Is there a known trend that good questions get closed because of poor answers?

Comment: Closure is not deletion or anything like it, so I don't see that that's anything other than "by design" (except for people carelessly using broken windows as bad examples, but that's unavoidable except by actually cleaning up the junk).

Comment: You can't vote to close on answers. I guess you mean vote to delete them.

Comment: @Tom, yes, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Can you explain the sequence of events you have in mind? In other words, how does the answer to a closed question end up on a review queue? I understand that it is possible, but I would like to know what possibility you are trying to deal with.

Comment: @Blackwood I'm not sure what sequence of events causes the issue. I only know that I come across these occasionally. I suppose an answer is flagged for being low quality, and while it's in the queue, the question gets closed for low quality. I just figure that 10 seconds spent deciding whether this answer to a useless question should be deleted is 10 seconds not spent reviewing some other question.

Comment: Okay. Then I think your suggestion is reasonable as long as it doesn't affect speedy removal of spam and abusive content, but I wouldn't consider it high priority.

Comment: The answers still prevent automatic deletion of those questions. It still seems worth it to delete answers that aren't really answers if they're keeping a bad question on the site.

Comment: @Tenfour04: The point you missed (which I didn't see earlier) was that questions are closed entirely *because they will produce* bad answers, and that's the only real underlying definition of a bad — or at least a closeable — question on Stack Exchange. That's why the only action taken in general on such a question is to stop it from getting answers. All the close reasons are just specific reifications of that philosophy that have proven fast enough and reliable enough to be useful in actual voting. (On SE, questions are not considered to be of any great value on their own.)

Comment: "experienced users of this site generally do not attempt to answer poor questions". False. They don't answer unanswerable questions. A "poor" on SO can often be a normal question in real life.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a good feature to implement.

The "not an answer" (NAA) and "very low quality" (VLQ) flags are going to the "Low Quality Posts" review queue (LQPQ). If we remove such answers from the review queue just because the question is closed, the NAA or VLQ post stays on the site. This is not a good thing at all. Low-quality posts and those that don't attempt to answer the question at all **should be removed** from the site.